# Type Arabic numbers in Arabic keyboard

Tags: macos, mac

You know that you are forced to type the Hindu-Arabic numbers (١٢٣٤...) in iOS and Mac OS if you are using the "Arabic Keyboard", so if you wanted to type English numbers ([which in fact called Arabic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) ) like (1234...) you will have to switch to the English keyboard, type the number, then get back to Arabic Keyboard.

Is there any way to override this? I am already using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to remap some keyboard keys, but it is not useful for the problem I am facing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arabic keyboards always have the ability to type English numbers built in.  Just hit the Caps Lock key in MacOS.

In iOS, try doing Press and Hold on a number key.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can change the keyboard arabic type, you see when you choose arabic as another typing language you should choose "Arabic - North Africa" from the system preference of your maciOS.

[image]